# Strange Determinsitic "Service Unavailable" Errors With Specific Calendars

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We've encountered a strange situation with some calendars that we are using the Graph API with. For these specific calendars, they always fail no matter what with a 5xx error (in the API as well as the Graph Explorer tool). As throttling is typically a transient issue - I do not believe this is a throttling problem (this always happens, even for a single request with 1 item). Here is an example request:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/USERNAME_REDACTED/calendars/AAMkAGZkNDEyOGQ4LTIyN2ItNDBmMi1hYWJjLTM2ZGYxN2NlYTc4NgBGAAAAAACgnt4958uoQrB-l5TUhV_yBwAMZiFRCXPBS41MYpHW-CHGAAAAAAEGAAAMZiFRCXPBS41MYpHW-CHGAAL-Z3lXAAA=/calendarView/microsoft.graph.delta?StartDateTime=2020-09-27T08%3A02%3A31.489&EndDateTime=2022-09-27T08%3A02%3A31.489
Prefer : odata.maxpagesize=1
SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.3.2
Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]
503 : Service Unavailable
```

Here are the specific request details (when run from the Graph Explorer):

```
date: 2021-09-21T20:31:16
requestId: d9a83b0e-1713-41c4-98e3-7ddbede90931
client-request-id: aec20073-350f-220d-78af-871e1ac9e5d1
```

A few questions:
Is there something 'wrong' with these calendar(s)? Maybe some problem with the Exchange server they reside on?
Is there some special situation causing the API to error out? (For example - permissions or something)